# find the 1 gem in 1000 with a neural net? something else?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, neural-network, classification

There's something I don't understand about neural networks. I've tried to use them with financial data analysis and audio pitch classification. In both cases, I need a classifier that can detect the significant item from among the many. My audio application literally has one positive hit for every thousand negative hits. I run the network trainer, and it learns that it's a pretty darn fine guess to just go with the negative. Is there some other algorithm for detecting the rare gem? Is there some form of neural network training that is especially suited for this type of problem? I can change the range on my positive data to be equivalent to the sum of the negative values, but I don't understand how that fits in with the preferred range of zero to one on the typical neural network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible suggestions:

1. **Balance your training set**

   Even if the real-world data contains 1000x as many negatives as positives, your training data does not have to. You can modify your training data set to increase the proportion of positives in your training set. That will improve the recall (more true positives), but also worsen the precision (also more false positives). So, you'd have to experiment with the ideal proportion of positives to negatives in the training set.

   This paper discusses this approach in more detail: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2243711/pdf/procamiasymp00003-0260.pdf
2. **Anomaly detection**

   ... on the other hand, if you have too few positive examples to train the neural network with a more balanced training set, then perhaps you could try [anomaly detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection). With anomaly detection, you train your algorithm (e.g., a neural network) to recognize what negative data points look like. Then, any data point that looks different than normal gets flagged as positive.

Comment: Anomaly detection algorithms appear to refer to a dataset that is different from all your other datasets. I need it to be more fine-grained than that -- something at the neuron level. However, I did manage to do a better job at balancing my training set.